# Javascript conditions to change menu position on scroll down

Tags: javascript

I'm a complete newbie to html/css and javascript but I have to create a simple website for a school project. I realised most of the things I wanted, but I would really like to add one extra element.

I have a horizontal menu that has a relative position top 500px and I would like it to move to a fixed position top 70px when people scroll down the page and come back to its original position when people go back to the top of the page. How can I do that?

Here's my menu code:

```
<header id="headermenu">
    <header id="blockMenu">

                <nav class="menuMain">
                    <ul>
                        <h2 style="font-size:small; font-weight:normal;"><li class="first"><a href="#jonction"><span>♢</span> JONCTION <span>♢</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#appropriation"><span>♢</span> APPROPRIATION <span>♢</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#partage"><span>♢</span> PARTAGE <span>♢</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="#info"><span>♢</span> Sur le projet <span>♢</span></a></li></h2>
                    </ul>
                </nav>   
    </header>
</header>
```

So, here's what I did now:

```
<script>

window.onscroll=function(){changeMenu()}

function changeMenu()
{
x=document.getElementById("blockMenu");
x.style.position = "fixed";
x.style.top = "70px";
}

</script>

<!-- END JS -->


    <header id="headermenu">
        <header id="blockMenu">

                    <nav class="menuMain">
                        <ul>
                            <h2 style="font-size:small; font-weight:normal;"><li class="first"><a href="#jonction"><span>♢</span> JONCTION <span>♢</span></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#appropriation"><span>♢</span>APPROPRIATION<span>♢</span></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#partage"><span>♢</span> PARTAGE <span>♢</span>/a></li><li><a href="#info"><span>♢</span>Sur le projet<span>♢</span></a></li></h2>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>   
        </header>
    </header>
```

The onscroll works perfectly, but I still don't know how to tell him that when people go back to the top of the page (is a long scroll down page) the menu has to go back to his original position.

Any suggestions?

I know I'm going to sound like a complete idiot, but hey... so here's what I did based on the fiddle, but nothing works anymore... Did I write something wrong or did I just not understand the principle?

```
<script>

window.onscroll=function(){changeMenu()}

function changeMenu()
{
var scrollBarPosition = window.pageYOffset | document.body.scrollTop;

if(scrollBarPosition == 0) {
    document.getElementById('blockMenu').style.position = "relative" +      document.getElementById('blockMenu').style.top = "500px";
}
else {
    document.getElementById('blockMenu').style.position = "fixed" +    document.getElementById('blockMenu').style.top = "70px";
}
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add a javascript handler to your document (DOM). There is a handler which recognizes scroll events. `window.onscroll = yourFunction;`. In `yourFunction` you can then read your documents current scrollBar position and then change the attributes of your menu accordingly to that. Hope this gets you further. If not please post your attempts you made already in javascript to make it easier to help specifically.

Comment: I edited my post so you can see what I did till now... I still don't understand how to make the menu go back to its original form once the user gets back to the top of the page.

Comment: Hi yes this looks good! Just check in your changeMenu function at what specific position the scrollBar is at the moment and determine so, if the user is on top of the page. Then decide what styling the menu should have. Does this help ?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I understand, how does the scrollBar bit work?

Comment: Sorry for the first JSFiddle, was not a good example try this http://jsfiddle.net/UFV7R/4/ . In firefox you need window.pageYOffset to get the actual scrollbar position in chrome its document.body.scrollTop.

Comment: Thanks for your time! I added to the post my recent edits based on your fiddle, but the java doesn't work anymore. Is my syntax wrong or is it something else?

Comment: Yes thats almost it! You can not just add another style attribute by concatinating with +. You should try document.getElementById('blockMenu').style.position = "relative"; document.getElementById('blockMenu').style.top = "500px";